# find specific string in spark sql--pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im trying to find an exact string match in a dataframe column from employee dataframe

```
Employee  days_present
Alex      1,2,11,23,
John      21,23,25,28
```

Need to find which employees are present on 2nd based on days_present column
expected output:
Alex

below is what i have tried

```
    df = spark.sql("select * from employee where days_present RLIKE '2')
    df.show()

This returns both Alex & John
```

**Also i would like to find out who are present on 2 & 11, in this case expected ouput is only ALex**

Comment: What if we `split()` the `days_present` field with `,`, and then explode the resulting array field. That way, you'll have a field of days present for all employee.

Answer (score 2):

We can use **`array_intersect`** function starting from Spark-2.4+ and then check the array size if **`size >=2`**

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
+--------+------------+
|Employee|days_present|
+--------+------------+
|    Alex|   1,2,11,23|
|    John| 21,23,25,28|
+--------+------------+
#DataFrame[Employee: string, days_present: string]

df.withColumn("tmp",split(col("days_present"),",")).\
withColumn("intersect",array_intersect(col("tmp"),array(lit("2"),lit("11")))).\
filter(size("intersect") >= 2).\
drop("tmp","intersect").\
show()

#+--------+------------+
#|Employee|days_present|
#+--------+------------+
#|    Alex|   1,2,11,23|
#+--------+------------+
```

---

**`In spark-sql:`**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

spark.sql("""select Employee,days_present from (select *,size(array_intersect(split(days_present,","),array("2","11")))size from tmp)e where size >=2""").show()

#+--------+------------+
#|Employee|days_present|
#+--------+------------+
#|    Alex|   1,2,11,23|
#+--------+------------+
```